# MVC Core 2.2 Image not displaying, 404 returned

Tags: image, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-2.2

MVC core 2.2 C#

What am I doing wrong?

I have been searching the web and seems I am following all advises. This isn't a complex situation, nonetheless it is not working.

The image shows all the setup.

- Image loaded in Image\logo.png
- Using @URL.Content
- I licked also in "Publish image" if it made any difference.

Image here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKQVz.jpg

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As no one answered...

Seems that you have to do more stuff in Core 3.1 than just calling the image. Images are now considered "static files" and you have to tell your application they exist:

On startup.cs

```
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
     FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
          Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"Images")), 
          RequestPath = "/Images"
            });
```

Also make sure that the image properties say "Copy To Output Directory":"Always", because this thing simply doesn't add the image to your build unless you tell it to do it.